# Scintilla error message on unrelated code

Tags: debugging, c#-4.0, scintilla

First off, ScintillaNET v2.6 was installed as a control and I have been able to use it and compile, so I assume the installation is ok:

This app is targeting the full .NET 4.0 framework, not the client profile)

Environment variable

[image]

ScintillaNT folder content

[image]

The error message:

[image]

The code triggering the error:

[image]

The error happens on the second line when I "step-in" the load method. Looks completely unrelated, but highly reproducible: the error always happens at that exact step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a corrupted XML file. I still don't know why the crash page was all about ScintillaNET, but it appears this had nothing to do with Scintilla.

I am not deleting this question because I could not find any indication that this could happen (errors in different parts of the code triggering a Scintilla error page) and it would have saved me a lot of time trying to track back the "scintilla" problem.